# Conway's Game of Life help me understand this unexpected output

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I would like some help understanding why my program is printing a grid of

```
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
...............OOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOO.......
....................
....................
....................
```

The correct output would be so:

```
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
.............O.O....
..............OO....
..............O.....
```

The way I wrote it is to create a copy of the old state and manipulate it using the rules of the game. After I check every cell, I store count of the number of neighbors alive for that cell. IF the count is greater than 3 or less than two, the cell will die.

If a cell has a count of 2 or 3 neighbors, it remains alive.
If a dead cell has a count of 3, it becomes alive.
These rules are directly applied to the copy version instead of the old and then print the copy.

I've tried using a debugger but I'm still unsure of how to use it properly. I haven't notice any red flags as of yet.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
vector<vector<bool> > world = {
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

void generate(const vector<vector<bool> >&g,vector<vector<bool> >&newworld)
{
    int count = 0;
    newworld = g;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < g.size();i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < g[i].size();j++) {
            int x = g.size(); //I rows
            int y = g[i].size(); //J columns
            //wrap the edges with formula (x+n)%n  where n = NumOfRows or NumOfCol
            if(g[(((i+1)+x)%x)][(((j-1)+y)%y)]==true){//top left
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[(((i+1)+x)%x)][j]==true){//top middle
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[(((i+1)+x)%x)][(((j+1)+y)%y)]==true){//top right
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[i][(((j-1)+y)%y)]==true){//left cell
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[i][(((j+1)+y)%y)]==true){//right cell
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[(((i-1)+x)%x)][(((j-1)+y)%y)]==true){ //bottom left
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[(((i-1)+x)%x)][j]==true){//bottom middle
            count++;
            }
             else if(g[(((i-1)+x)%x)][(((j+1)+y)%y)]==true){//bottom right
            count++;
            }

        if (g[i][j]) {
            if(count > 3 || count < 2) {//if alive cell has more than 3 or less than 2, die
            newworld[i][j] = false;
            }
            else if (count == 2 || count == 3) { //remain the same 
                newworld[i][j] = g[i][j];
            }
        }
        else if (g[i][j] == false) {//dead come alive
        if(count == 3) {
        newworld[i][j] = true;
        }

            }
        }
    }
}

void display(vector<vector<bool> >&a)
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row <a.size(); row++) {
        for(size_t column = 0; column <a[row].size(); column++){
            if (a[row][column]) {
                cout << 'O';
            }
             else {
                cout << '.';
             }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }          
}        

int main()
{
    vector<vector<bool> > newworld;
    generate(world,newworld);
    display(newworld);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I only skimmed it, but your problem is likely `newworld = g;`. Unless I'm mistaken, that line doesn't create a copy of `g`, and you must modify a copy of the previous world; not the original.

Comment: Advice -- If you have trouble debugging, why not start out with a smaller grid and go step-by-step to see where things fail?  Once you get a smaller grid to work, then and only then should you try larger ones.  If a 5 x 10 or smaller grid fails, then you aren't going to get a 10 x 20 to magically work, so stick with a smaller data set and debug that instead.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  My reasoning for the way I wrote that was to modify the original because if I were to modify the copy, it would be updating itself after each line. By searching through the original i can find all the neighbors and then update the copy with the new generation with one step.

Comment: You're not counting correctly.  Reexamine how you're computing the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `generate` has (at least) two problem.

- `count` is initialized *outside* the nested loops, so it's never reset to zero (as it should, for every cell) and keeps growing.
- All the conditions are mutually exclusive, so whenever one it's met, the others are skipped. There shouldn't be any `else if`, but only `if`s.

Keeping the data structure you chose, you can rewrite that function as

```
using gof_t = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;

void generate(gof_t& g, gof_t& newworld)
{
    for(size_t i = 0, x = g.size(); i < x; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0, y = g[i].size(); j < y; j++)
        {
            size_t i_prev = (i + x - 1) % x;
            size_t i_next = (i + 1) % x;
            size_t j_prev = (j + y - 1) % y;
            size_t j_next = (j + 1) % y;

            int count = g[i_prev][j_prev] + g[i_prev][j] + g[i_prev][j_next]
                      + g[i     ][j_prev]                + g[i     ][j_next]
                      + g[i_next][j_prev] + g[i_next][j] + g[i_next][j_next];

            newworld[i][j] = g[i][j] ? (count == 2 || count == 3) : (count == 3);
        }
    }
    std::swap(g, newworld); // <-- Passing by non const reference, we can swap without copying
}
```

Live (pun intended), [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RagPqrAdDdNnE7NU).